# performance: store a large mysql result in class vars VS result array

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Hej folks,

i was wondering what is faster. Suggest we have a big database table with about 50 columns and a class that handles these columns.

The class constructor loads all fields - and here starts my question.

Is it useful to store every column in an own class variable or is this juts unperformant?
In this case i already have a array, e.g. $result which keys are the table columns.

Or is this irrelevant?

I tried to write a benchmark but i only have a vServer to test so the results are not very clear.

Is a one time function that stores the values in class vars faster then searching the whole array for every 'get' method?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S.
PHP 5

Comment: FYI, you don't need to write a function to store the result in an object - just specify `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` when calling `PDOStatement::Fetch`

Comment: hmm i'm using a customized mysqli class. Also I have created classes for diffrent mysql tables, e.g. employees, projects etc.. Don't know what this would do.
my question is, whether its useful to store the result in class vars form eployee or store a array.
e.g. `employee::$id, employee::$name vs employee::$result['id'], employee::$result['name']` (no these fields are not public, its just an example) thus to get an object i colud use mysqli_fetch_object ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is "it doesn't really matter".

In terms of application performance, the code you're talking about - iterating over a loop in memory 50 times and manipulating data in memory, retrieving class data, or retrieving data from an associative array - is blazingly fast. So fast that it's almost impossible to measure differences under normal circumstances. In order to notice any difference between `employee::$id, employee::$name` vs `employee::$result['id'], employee::$result['name']`you'd have to be dealing with extreme circumstances - a $result array of millions of columns, for instance. See [this](http://aggregation.novaak.net/?q=node/227) benchmark.

On the other hand, from a design point of view, there are some trade-offs - by mapping the result to class variables, you can hide business logic, and create a consistent interface. For instance, if your employee class needs to calculate annual_salary based on the database field monthly_salary, you can create another class variable called "annual_salary", and client code is always consistent - it's `employee::annual_salary` and `employee::monthly_salary`, not `employee::result['monthly_salary']` and `employee::annual_salary`.

Comment: so as i thought i doesn't really mater. also i have no public fields, everything is encapsulated in the Class and only accessible with get/set methods. But the benchmark is nice, seems its not a big differene. In this case store everything in class variables should decrease the perfomance because i store it twice. Thanks so far